# Gallery - custom html for inserting images

Tags: gallery, images, links

I have gallery (I'm using [Cleaner Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cleaner-gallery/) plugin) with many images. I want to add asynchronous image loading with jQuery (I'm using [JAIL](http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail) to do that). But to use this JAIL plugin I need to change gallery output (need to use data-href tag with link to image). How can I do that? I've been trying to edit cleaner-gallery.php inside my plugin directory but id does not change anything!

@edit:
Changing cleaner-gallery.php doesn't give wanted output. I don't know why but maybe I have to edit some function from wp-includes/media.php? Do you know what function should I overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

In cleaner-gallery.php make changes to the cleaner_gallery_plugin_gallery_image function that starts on line 122 and ends on line 151.

What we are doing is replacing href with data-href in the two instances that output the html with the image attributes.

```
function cleaner_gallery_plugin_gallery_image( $image, $id, $attr, $instance ) {

    /* If the image should link to nothing, remove the image link. */
    if ( 'none' == $attr['link'] ) {
        $image = preg_replace( '/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', '$1', $image );
    }

    /* If the image should link to the 'file' (full-size image), add in extra link attributes. */
    elseif ( 'file' == $attr['link'] ) {
        $attributes = cleaner_gallery_link_attributes( $instance );

        if ( !empty( $attributes ) )
            $image = str_replace( '<a href=', "<a{$attributes} data-href=", $image );
    }

    /* If the image should link to an intermediate-sized image, change the link attributes. */
    elseif ( in_array( $attr['link'], get_intermediate_image_sizes() ) ) {

        $post = get_post( $id );
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $attr['link'] );

        $attributes = cleaner_gallery_link_attributes( $instance );
        $attributes .= " data-href='{$image_src[0]}'";
        $attributes .= " title='" . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . "'";

        $image = preg_replace( '/<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', "<a{$attributes}>$1</a>", $image );
    }

    /* Return the formatted image. */
    return $image;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to edit same part of code but it doesn't change anything. Also, in Cleaner Gallery settings I've changed images to link to nothing but it doesn't work! So maybe this plugin doesn't work at all for me? How can I check it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you caching your site?

If not, the function `cleaner_gallery_plugin_gallery_image` in *cleaner-gallery.php* (v0.9.2) works with the variable `$image`. This is the image HTML as a string. Some regex magic should then be able to achieve what you want.